# MySQL - Display data between 2 dates using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, date, inner-join

How do I display the rooms that are not on the range of the checkInDate and checkOutDate column of the **tblreserve** table?

tblcustomer

```
customerID | Fname | Lname
1          | John  | Smith
```

tblreservation

```
reservationID | customerID | reserveDate | checkInDate | checkOutDate
1             | 1          | 2015-09-09  | 2015-09-10  | 2015-09-11
```

tblroom

```
roomID | roomTypeID | roomStatusID | roomNumber | floorNumber
1      | 1          | 1            | 101        | 1
2      | 2          | 1            | 102        | 1
3      | 3          | 1            | 103        | 1
```

tblroomreserve

```
roomID | reservationID
1      | 1
```

tblroomstatus

```
roomStatusID | roomStatus
1            | vacant
2            | occupied
3            | reserved
```

tblroomtype

```
roomTypeID | roomType
1          | Single Room
2          | Double Room
3          | Twin Room
```

I tried the INNER JOIN but instead of displaying all the rooms on the **tblroom** table that are not occupied on a range of two inputted dates, it only displays the room on the **tblreserve** table that does not fall on the range of a specific date. i.e. '2015-09-12' and '2015-09-13'

```
SELECT
    `tblroom`.`roomNumber`
    , `tblroomtype`.`roomTypeDescription`
    , `tblroomtype`.`roomRate`
FROM
    `hotelreservation`.`tblreservation`
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblcustomer` 
    ON (`tblreservation`.`customerID` = `tblcustomer`.`customerID`)
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblroomreservation` 
    ON (`tblroomreservation`.`reservationID` = `tblreservation`.`reservationID`)
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblroom` 
    ON (`tblroomreservation`.`roomID` = `tblroom`.`roomID`)
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblroomstatus` 
    ON (`tblroom`.`roomStatusID` = `tblroomstatus`.`roomStatusID`)
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblroomtype` 
    ON (`tblroom`.`roomTypeID` = `tblroomtype`.`roomTypeID`)
    AND NOT tblreservation.`checkInDate` >= '2015-09-12' AND tblreservation.`checkOutDate` <= '2015-09-13'
```

Comment: Provided schema and schema used in query doesn't match

Comment: Sorry. Corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work for you:

```
SELECT
  tblroom.roomNumber,
  tblroomtype.roomTypeDescription,
  tblroomtype.roomRate
FROM tblroom
INNER JOIN tblroomtype
  ON tblroom.roomTypeID = tblroomtype.roomTypeID
WHERE roomID NOT IN (SELECT
  tblroomreservation.roomID
FROM tblreservation
INNER JOIN tblroomreservation
  ON (tblroomreservation.reservationID = tblreservation.reservationID)
WHERE checkInDate BETWEEN '2015-09-12' AND '2015-09-13');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54d2a/5

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
    `tblroom`.`roomNumber`
    , `tblroomtype`.`roomTypeDescription`
    , `tblroomtype`.`roomRate`
FROM
    `hotelreservation`.`tblreservation`
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblcustomer` 
    ON (`tblreservation`.`customerID` = `tblcustomer`.`customerID`)
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblroomreservation` 
    ON (`tblroomreservation`.`reservationID` = `tblreservation`.`reservationID`)
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblroom` 
    ON (`tblroomreservation`.`roomID` = `tblroom`.`roomID`)
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblroomstatus` 
    ON (`tblroom`.`roomStatusID` = `tblroomstatus`.`roomStatusID`)
INNER JOIN `hotelreservation`.`tblroomtype` 
    ON (`tblroom`.`roomTypeID` = `tblroomtype`.`roomTypeID`
    AND tblreservation.`checkInDate` between '2015-09-12' AND '2015-09-13')
```

Comment: Try adding "tblreservation.`checkInDate` between '2015-09-12' AND '2015-09-13'" to where clause